# Draw performance in canvas

Tags: android, android-studio, canvas, android-canvas, bitmapfactory

I am using draw function in my app

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
   if (canvas != null)
      canvas.drawBitmap(animation.getImage(), x, y, null);
}
```

This function is further invoked in main thread

```
try {
   canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
   synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
      this.gamePanel.update();
      this.gamePanel.draw(canvas);
   }
}
```

When I draw one PNG file (1800 x 1000 px) the frame rate is about 60 FPS,
but when I separate this image to 3 files (600 x 1000 px) and draw them separately the framerate drops to 40 FPS.
I need to have more smaller images, beacause I want the parallax effect and other things in the app, but how to increase the performence of that separate drawing?

Comment: Looks like you develop a game, so I highly recommend you using a simple 2D game engine for this. The drawBitmap function is expensive. In general working with bitmaps is hard on Android (you can easily get OutOfMemory errors). Related question: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/186340/android-canvas-drawbitmap-gives-an-awful-performance

Comment: Canvas is not well suited to this. Every time you draw a bitmap, it has to transfer all that image data to the GPU, which is expensive. This should be done in OpenGL ES or Vulkan with persistently loaded textures. Or use a game engine. For Android, the predominant low-level Java-based game engine is libGDX.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Finally I used libGDX. Now it is much faster and smooth

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I was contemplating for months on whether I should build a game in canvas or use libgdx. Luckily I stumbled across this answer.